# ad-hoc policy lock

Tags: native-assets, policy

It's possible to create a policy which can no longer be used to mint/burn after a given slot. The following object in a `policy.script` handles that:

```
{
      "type": "before",
      "slot": <insert slot here>
}
```

What if, however, one does not include this block (no `before` object in script) but eventually wants to lock the policy to prevent future burning/minting? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The contents of the script itself are used to actual generate the Policy ID. Once you mint something under that policy ID it's impossible to make a change.